# Task scheduled as a cronjob not executing

Tags: cron, zsh, scheduling, cron-task

On my Macos 11.6.1, I want to execute a script 'task1.zsh' with the following content

```
#!/bin/zsh

/usr/bin/touch /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt
echo hello >> /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/hello.txt
```

the file `task1.zsh` has the following permissions:

```
-rwxr-x--x   1 user  staff   116B Jun 18 00:15 task1.zsh*
```

I inserted the following task with cronjob (with the following output of the command `crontab -l`:

```
* * * * * /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/task1.zsh
```

with this cronjob, however the file "hello.txt" is not created nor populated.
I also tried to replace

```
* * * * * /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/task1.zsh
```

by:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/ && ./task1.zsh
```

as well as

```
* * * * * /bin/zsh /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs/task1.zsh
```

or

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs /bin/zsh task1.zsh
```

without success.

However If I had the following other task to the cronjob list:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && /bin/zsh task1.zsh
* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && echo check >> cron1.log
```

the file `cron1.log` gets created and gets populated by the string "check" (but the file `hello.txt` does not get created nor populated)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `touch` to `/usr/bin/touch`. If that works, it's a problem with the path. If it doesn't work, then I hope someone else can spot the issue, because I can't see it :).

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @Gairfowl. I tried your hint (and edited the question accordingly). Unfortunatelyit did not work.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem with your original solution. I would first verify, whether the crontab is processed at all. You could put the _touch_ command directly into your crontab, without a script. Is the file created (with a reasonable new timestamp)? Also: Under which user id is the cronjob executed? I don't know enough about Macos, but perhaps cron needs to be enabled somehow if you want to use it? I have the impression, that the problem is not related to zsh, and suggest that you ask this instead at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment @user1934428. So i added another task to the cronjob (namely `* * * * * cd /Users/user/Documents/cronjobs && echo check >> cron1.log`) and this one gets executed.

Comment: I will ask the same question on Ask Differen then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comment of Gordon Davisson in this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/314206/ecjb, I went to Security and Privacy and granted full disk access to cron and it worked